# How to add library to project in Android Studio 1.0.2?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, libraries

First, this is not duplicate. I have browsed answers to "How to add library to project in Android Studio" but found no answer. I cant find `src` and `libs` folder. I want to add volley jar to project. Screenshot attached:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SyUp.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: The structure of folder seems to be not correct in your screenshot. Android Studio uses Gradle and it is recommended to include dependencies into build.gradle file.

Comment: Switch your view from "Android" to "Project" and you will see a libs directory. Right above demoCardView1, you see "Android" with and arrow down, click that to change to Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For preferred way read bellow this answer:**

If you need to add a library to the Android Studio project navigate to your project folder with default path at:
*\YourProjectName\app\libs*

You can paste your *.jar library there. Make sure your build.gradle contain this directive at dependencies part:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

To see the library at the Android Studio, switch to the "Project" view at the menu:
[image: Android Studio Project view]

**Preffered way:**

Preferred way to import libraries to your project is by gradle dependency system.
To do so, open your build.gradle file and locate the **dependencies** part. To import the library you mentioned, Volley, your dependencies part should look somehow like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.10'
}
```

You don't need to import the *.jar library manually any more. Gradle dependencies system will take care of it.

To find gradle dependency you need, you might use tools like:

http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

http://search.maven.org/

Comment: I am getting this error:

Could not find property 'include' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@188a3e1a.